# How to automatically play next song on a list

Tags: c#, playlist, windows-media-player

I'm making a musicplayer for my downloaded songs. I got it to play the songs I select but I would like the next song to start automatically after the previous one ended.

I've tried using the PlayStateChange event but it doesn't seem to work, when trying to debug (F11) it just doesn't do anything after the song ended.

```
private void lstSongs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            index = lstSongs.SelectedIndex;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[lstSongs.SelectedIndex];

        }
```

this is the code to play the selected song

```
void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange()
        {
            index++;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[lstSongs.SelectedIndex];
        }
```

this is the last thing I tried but it just doesn't execute that code

I expected it to just go to the next song on the list, I don't get any errors

Comment: You appear to be modifying an `index` variable, but never use it.

Comment: From the [PlayStateChange Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WMP/axwmplib-axwindowsmediaplayer-playstatechange) documentation: "Windows Media Player states are not guaranteed to occur in any particular order. Furthermore, not every state necessarily occurs during a sequence of events. You should not write code that relies upon state order."

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to build a **playlist** of all the songs instead of playing them one by one, that way the next song in the playlist would automatically play after the last one finishes:

```
WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist Playlist = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newPlaylist("MyPlayList", "");
foreach(String song in lstSongs.Items)
{
    Playlist.appendItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(song));
}
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = Playlist;
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

It's unclear if you will have multiple selections in your listbox, or if you want to play all entries in the listbox.

You can get the currently playing song when it changes with:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (e.newState == 3)
    {
        label1.Text = "Playing: " + axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.name;
    }    
}
```