# After a video file ends, how would I get the next video to play without setting a timer?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have put together a list of files that I want played from a specific directory. The videos/pictures are displayed on Windows Media Player. After the end of one video, I want the play button to be pressed to play the next video. Currently, my code is set up to have a button pressed to go to the next file in the list, as well as a play button being pressed to display the image (buttons are pressed using a timer, but this is inconvenient because some videos do not get played for the full time). Video URLS are pulled from textboxes that are filled with xml or file path information.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.stretchToFit = true;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";         //disables the play, pause, etc. buttons at the bottom of the windows media player//  
            listView1.Items.Clear();    //clears listview items//
            Repopulate();   //calls repopulate function//
            refreshtimer.Interval = 5 * 60 * 1000;
            //timer for when images need to be displayed//
            Timer tmr = new Timer();
            int result = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);           
            tmr.Interval = result * 60 * 1001; 
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            tmr.Start();        
        }
        private void Repopulate()
        {
            foreach (var d in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBox3.Text))
            {
                var dirName = new DirectoryInfo(d).Name;
                listView1.Items.Add(dirName);
            }
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                listBox1.Items.Add(item.Text);
            }
        }
        //hidden button that acts as a "play" button, taking url from textbox 1, playing the video, and looping it until it is time for the next image//
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show(textBox4.Text);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = textBox4.Text; 
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("loop", true);
        
        }
        
        // timer that clicks button one//
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            button1.PerformClick();    
        }

        private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
        {        
        }
        //when the tvdisplay is shown, start button is clicked and button 1 (play button) is clicked//
        private void TVDisplay_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startbutton.PerformClick();
            button1.PerformClick();          
        }
        //hidden behind windows media player//
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer tmr = new Timer();
            int result = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            tmr.Interval = result * 60 * 1000;
            //int result = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);           
           // tmr.Interval = 1 * 60 * 1000;
            //tmr.Interval = 180000;
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
            tmr.Start();
            //textBox2.Clear();
            var path = textBox3.Text;
            textBox4.Text = path + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        private void refreshtimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.BeginUpdate();
            int x = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            Repopulate();
            //selects the first index once files are repopulated//
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = x;
            listBox1.EndUpdate();
        }
        //hidden behind windows media display//
        private void startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startbutton.Enabled = false;
            timer3.Interval = 10000; //time in milliseconds
            timer3.Tick += timer3_Tick;
            timer3.Start();
            //startbutton.Enabled = false;
            if(listBox1.Items != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no content entered for display.", "Error");
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else { 
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = (listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) % listBox1.Items.Count; 
            }
           
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startbutton.PerformClick();
        }

        private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startbutton.Enabled = true;
            timer3.Stop();
        }
    }
```

If a timer is the most practical element to use, what would be a better way to implement it?

Comment: Can you subscribe to the [mediaended](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediaended?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event?

Comment: [PlayStateChange Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwmplib-axwindowsmediaplayer-playstatechange) -- Note that, as of now, you're adding a new event handler to your Timers (which you don't really need) each time a Button is pressed or an item is selected in a ListBox. That's not the right way. Add the event handler just once -- Note that you could create a play list

Comment: Thank you both, I was unaware of these event handlers and it seems like one of these will solve my issue.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56382875/2330053) for some example code.